# Hardware TnL Failure

Tags: dell-inspiron, intel-graphics

I was recently given a stack of "Old" games on CDs.  I've been able to load and install quite a few so far and play them with no trouble.

However, I have one game that comes up with two error messages.  " Cannot find D3D, please install latest version of DirectX 8 or above"  The other message says that " my computer failed the Hardware TnL" and to check video card for ability to handle.

I have a Dell 3000 running Win XP Pro, running a Pentium 4 @2.80 GHZ, and have 2Gb of onboard ram.  I have Intel Graphics Chip 82865.  My latest Direct X is 9.0c, and so is the D3D module.

Now the game has system test software, and when it scans my system I keep getting the TnL error.  an

Any ideas would be helpful.

Thanks for your time and consideration.

Jerry

Answer (score 2):

The TnL error pops up when you have either an unsupported graphics adapter, no graphics card at all, or when you have an onboard adapter and it is trying to use that instead of your addon. If you have an onboard graphics adapter, try disabling it and then uninstalling / reinstalling the game.

Answer (score 0):

It appears that the chip [does not](http://www.intel.com/support/graphics/sb/cs-011910.htm) have support for hardware transformation and lighting.

The solution is to get another video card.